# Number of permutations of the letters $a, b, c, d$ such that $b$ does not follow $a$, and $c$ does not follow $b$, and $d$ does not follow $c$

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

> **QUESTION:** Find the  number  of  permutations  of  the  letters  $a,  b,  c,  d$  such  that  $b$ does  not  follow $a$,  and  $c$  does  not  follow  $b$,  and  $d$  does  not  follow $c$.

---

**MY ANSWER**

> I know this is a simple problem but I need an explanation as to why my logic is wrong

Firstly, we group $(ab)$ together, so we get $3!$ permutations in which $a$ and $b$ occur together in that order.. Similarly, we do it for $(bc)$ and $(cd)$ to get permutations that are *not required*..

So we do, $(4!-3!-3!-3!)$.. but obviously, there are repeated cases and we need to take care of that..

Now, thinking about this I came across a solution which stated that $(ab)$ can arrange in $2!$ ways (obviously) so, we just add them up to correct the sum..
Same goes for $(bc)$ and $(cd)$ ..

This means, when we *subtracted the cases*, **we must have subtracted these cases too for which we have to add now**..

But when did we do that! To make myself clear, I put forward an example..

Suppose we can arrange $(bc)$ in $2!$ ways so we consider the case -

$$a(cb)d$$

We are adding this up right? But when did we even subtract this case so that we have to add it now? We did permutations of
$$(ab)cd,\space a(bc)d,\space ab(cd)$$ And however you may permute any of these three, you will never get the configuration  $a(cb)d$  because for the first one, there is an $a$ attached *before* $b$ so $c$ cannot come before $b$, in the second one, we have $(bc)$ and **not** $(cb)$ and in the third one, there is a $d$ attached *after* $c$ so we cannot have $b$ after $c$. So why do we even subtract that? What does that mean?

The solution I saw ended in saying that $(ab)$ can arrange in $2!$ ways, so can $(bc)$ and $(cd)$ and that $(bcd)$ can arrange in $1!$ way... Why?!

From where does $(bcd)$ arrange in $1!$ way?

And then, what seemed like the application of inclusion and exclusion principle, the answer looks like-

$$4!-3.3!+3.2!-1=11$$

Can anyone please help me understand the meaning of what is said.. where is my thinking going wrong?

> Please don't answer that this can be done just by brute force.. I know that :').. what I need to know is just where is *my* thought process going wrong?

Thank you so much for your kind help and advice :)..

Comment: Could you explain yourself a bit @sammy gerbil

Comment: @Stranger Forever, if you allow I've an alternate method.

Comment: @SarGe Yes absolutely.. What is the method that you think of?

Comment: @sammy gerbil I get you, it's really confusing..

Comment: You know, there are only $24$ permutations of $a,b,c,d$. You could write them all down, and cross out the ones that violate the conditions, and count up how many are left, in about one-tenth the time it took you to write up your question.

Comment: @Gerry Myerson Thanks for your help, but I know that.. My question was different... I asked 'where' is my logic wrong?

Answer (score 2):

It's difficult to sneak through your spirals. I'd argue as follows:

A priori there are $24$ possible words. $6$ of them contain $(ab)$, and $6$ of them contain $(cd)$, whereby $2$ contain both pairs. This excludes $6+6-2=10$ words. There are $6$ words containing $bc$. The three  words
$$(bc)\ a\ d,\quad d\ (bc)\ a, \quad a\ d\ (bc)$$
have not occurred before, but in each of these  the interchange of $a$ and $d$ would create an $(ab)$ or a $(cd)$. In this way we obtain $3$ more forbidden words, so that there are $11$ admissible words left.

Answer (score 0):

This method is equally lengthy as your but more clearer. Fix $a$ in first position and select the favorable cases. $$\begin{align} \underline{\color{red}{a}}\,&\underline b\,\underline c \,\underline d\;\checkmark\\ 
&\underline b\,\underline d\,\underline c\;\times\\
&\underline c\,\underline b\,\underline d\;\times\\
&\underline c\,\underline d\,\underline b\;\checkmark\\
&\underline d\,\underline b\,\underline c\;\times\\
&\underline d\,\underline c\,\underline b \;\checkmark\end{align}$$

Hence, there are three favourable cases. Do it similarly for $b,c$ and $d$, you will get the answer as $11$.